# Unable to add event listener to a button inside javascript class

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to attach the event listener to all the buttons having the class "`shop-item-button`"
pizzaMenu.js. I've already tried doing it but the function `addToCartClicked()` is never getting called even when I click on the button. Also, the loop for adding event listener in pizzaMenu.js is not executing(I tried to debug).
Link for the entire code:https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-robinson-bsn5g?from-embed=&file=/src/pizzaMenu.js

```
class pizzaMenu extends Section {
  addToCartClicked(event) {
    console.log("Add to Cart triggered");
    let button = event.target;
    //function definition etc
    }
  }

  constructor(title) {
    super();
  }
  render(app) {
    fetch("data.json")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Check 1");
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        data.pizza.forEach((item) => {
          const pizzaMenuEl = this.createSection();

          console.log("Check 2");
          pizzaMenuEl.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="shop-item" id="${item.id}">
                        <div class="shop-item-details">
                            <div class = "shop-item-sizes">
                                <input type="radio" value="100" name="sizes">
                                <label>Small</label>
                                <input type="radio" value="200" name="sizes">
                                <label>Medium</label>
                                <input type="radio" value="300" name="sizes">
                                <label>Large</label>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button">ADD TO CART</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>`;

          app.appendChild(pizzaMenuEl);
          
        });
      });
    //adding the Event Listener to "Add to Cart" buttons
    const btns = document.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-button");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", this.addToCartClicked);
    }
  }
}
```

section.js

```
class Section {
  // Classes must be passed as an array
  createSection(cssClasses) {
    const sectionEl = document.createElement("div");
    sectionEl.classList.add("row");

    if (cssClasses) {
      for (const cssClass of cssClasses) {
        sectionEl.classList.add(cssClass);
      }
    }

    return sectionEl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just don't go through all the buttons but set the event handler to the click event of the parent.

```
app.addEventListener('click', this.addToCartClicked);
```

In the addToCartClicked function you could then check whether a button element has been clicked and handle it.

```
if(event.target.classList.contains('shop-item-button')) {
    return;
}
```

or

```
if(event.target.tagName !== 'button') {
    return;
}
```